# Building a very secure CMS

Tags: security, drupal

I've done a basic search online and found that Drupal is able to do the job my client requests. It's basically a user login which takes them to a form which they can use to query a database and submit data etc.

My question is what are the most important things to think about if security is absolute number 1 priority for this system? Are there any particular modules in Drupal I should use, or a particular area I really need to look into?

Comment: "what are the most important things to think about if security is absolute number 1 priority for this system?" -- don't connect it to the internet? Leave the server powered off? Oh, the system must also be usable? Then security isn't the #1 priority.

Answer (score 1):

Please check http://groups.drupal.org/node/20504 for details.

More to this these are the modules you can check out for security purpose.

http://drupalmodules.com/category/Security